how do I go beyond automated black box job application rejection mails and find out actual reason of rejection?
Getting a job application rejection is okay, perhaps better than not getting any communication whatsoever from the company that one applied for.
Getting the rejected result mail from a no-reply account is the norm these days, and most of the rejection mails use formal language to politely notify about rejection, but do not provide any insight into the factors that lead to the rejection. I understand that for companies it would become tedious to explain it to every candidate.
But from an applicant's POV, unless I am able to pin-point the reason why I was rejected, I cannot fix that reason and have a better chance of getting selected.
I observe a factor here:
Either there are too many people competing for a handful of jobs which can only be caught by either outstanding credentials/resume or through a referral.
Should I use the ATS tools to have an evaluation of likelihood of me getting a breakthrough ?
Also I want to present two excerpts from different rejection mails and I would like to know do they have subtle difference or they both sound different but ultimately mean the same thing:
Rejection 1:

We have reviewed your application and have decided not to move forward
for the XYZ role at this time. We are always
hiring and hope you’ll continue to explore opportunities with us as
they become available.

Rejection 2:

After reviewing your work and experience, we've made the decision to
not move forward at this time. We hope you don't mind if we reach out
to you in the future when a position opens up that may be a good fit.

Rejection 3:

While we were impressed with your skillset and accomplishments, we
regret to inform you that we won't be able to offer you a suitable
position at this time.

Would like to be able to read exactly between the lines.

There are no lines to read between. Nobody typed these just for you, I'm afraid they are almost certainly stock rejection letters.

Don't waste your time trying to beat the softwares that reject you. Keep applying and you will have better chances of getting interviews. Not all companies use those non-sense software (or silly AI) to read the resumes.

VTC - I don't think there is an answerable question here and if there is one - it's going to be highly opinionated.

@JoeStrazzere yes

If you want better feedback (and if you want to improve your chances), network with others and apply using referrals. ATS systems are not designed for the benefit of job-hunters.


how do I go beyond automated black box job application rejection mails
and find out actual reason of rejection?

If rejections came in response to an application, rather than actual interviews, compare the listed job requirements to the skills and experience on your resume. Be brutally honest with yourself. If possible, enlist a friend who will be brutally honest.
You can always send a note to the hiring manager, but don't expect a response any more detailed than the boilerplate mail you have received so far. When I was a hiring manager, I would never say more than something like "We decided to go in a different direction."
While it may be important for you, there is no advantage to the hiring company to provide specific reasons for their rejection. It's not their job to coach you up for your next interview. It's not their job to give you things to work on. Their only job is to find a suitable candidate and hire them. So far, that's not you.
You can ask your friends and professional network for feedback. If you are open to constructive criticism, you might get some helpful responses, or you might not. And if you have friends within the hiring company, you might get some confidential feedback, but probably not.
If you are going through an agency you can ask for feedback. That may or may not prove to be useful.
Ultimately, it's up to you to figure out why you don't get the job. Keep really good notes on the jobs you apply for and everything you said and heard during the interviews (if any). You might start to see a pattern. It might be that you aren't good enough for the jobs you are seeking. Or it might be that someone else was a bit better. Often, you can never really know.

You can't.
There are no lines to read between in the emails.  They are just form letters.  Someone wrote up a generic rejection message and they send that email to all unsuccessful candidates.  There are no subtle messages to discren.
Companies are strongly incentivized not to give you any information.  It's a lot of work for them.  Doing so opens them up to lawsuits if someone misinterprets a suggestion as discriminatory.  And it creates more work as applicants now want to explain exactly how the actual reasons are invalid.  And most of the time, the company has no idea the answer because someone scanned your resume for 30 seconds and decided it wasn't one of the 10 most promising applications to invest time following up with.
Yes, if you don't get feedback it is hard to improve.  The issue is that the company has no incentive to spend the time to provide that feedback so you'll be a better fit somewhere else.  That's all cost and no benefit to them.  If you really want feedback, there are professional resume review services that would be more than happy to give you whatever level of feedback you would like to pay for.  Most people, though, rely on friends and family for feedback or go searching online for information on how to write a resume, how to present yourself in an interview, etc.

And the exact premise of the rejection is not necessarily open to everyone. Maybe the CEO's nephew suddenly needed a job?
